# Difference between setIdentity and setCredential in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

What is the difference between `setIdentity` and `setCredential` in Zend Framework?

```
$authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('username')
       ->setCredentialColumn('password');

$authAdapter->setIdentity($data['username'])
        ->setCredential($data['password']);
```

Please help me I need some detailed explanation.

Comment: Why -1 what is the problem in my questions?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**identityColumn**: This is the name of the database table column used to represent the identity. The identity column must contain unique values, such as a username or e-mail address.

**credentialColumn**: This is the name of the database table column used to represent the credential. Under a simple identity and password authentication scheme, the credential value corresponds to the password. See also the credentialTreatment option.

Basically, **setIdentity** tells the system to set a username and **setCredential** tells the system to set the provided password for authentication.

Hope it helps.
Ref: [Zend Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html)